# What kind of optimizations do both the C# compiler and the JIT do?

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-construction, jit

I'm continuing my work on my C# compiler for my Compilers Class.  At the moment I'm nearly finished with the chapters on Compiler Optimizations in my textbook.

For the most part, my textbook didn't have Just-In-Time compilation in mind when it was written and I'm curious about the kinds of static, pre-jit optimizations the C# compiler performs versus what it does during the JIT process?

When I talk to people about compiling against the CLR, I typically hear things like, "Most of the optimizations are done by the JIT".

Are things like loop unrolling, constant folding/propagation, instruction interweaving done pre-Jit by C#'s compiler or handled by the jitter?  If they aren't handled by the jitter, then what kind of optimizations does the jitter do that are unique to a just-in-time compiler?

Comment: Most of the optimizations you mention are done by the jitter. The C# compiler does constant folding because that is required by the language semantics. The C# compiler run with /o just does simple IL control flow optimizations, like eliminating "branch to next instruction". This is a good topic; I'll see if I can knock up a blog article on what optimizations we do at the IL level. Watch my blog in the next month or so for details. –

Comment: @Eric Lippert, Nice! Wasn't expecting a response from a senior developer on the Microsoft compiler team!  If you remember to, when you make your blog post, be sure to link to it from here.  I'll be keeping an eye out anyway.  Thanks Eric.

Comment: You're welcome. The article will go up on June 11th.

Comment: Article is up at: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I can imagine there being a number of optimizations that are unique to JIT; specifically, any optimization that depends on the environment/context that the application runs in. (Note, all the following are hypothetical, I do not know for sure, which or if any of these are actually performed)

Most boring: the JIT can optimize depending on 32-bit/64-bit underlying OS, or even potentially depending on the exact processor architecture.

**Not applicable:** *More interesting: the JIT could optimize out anything that only runs in Debug mode (certain conditional code for example) when the application is not run inside a debug context.*

Most interesting: the JIT could optimize out conditional branches in a class that depend only on a `readonly` field, because at least theoretically that value will never change during the execution of the class.

Basically I'd imagine that deferring optimizations until JIT would generally be the way to go, because at JIT time there is the most information available about the context the code is actually running in, making more meaningful optimizations possible.

Comment: Debug-only code is removed by the C# compiler, not by the jitter.

Answer (score 0):

David Notario has a few posts on his blog (you can [start here](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidnotario/archive/2004/10.aspx), and then walk the history), but they are rather sketchy.

Answer (score -5):

I don't think the C# compiler does any optimizations.  The JIT does all the work.

Comment: Since debug and release builds are different on the IL level the compiler does some optimizations.

Comment: I believe this reasoning is faulty (e.g. in 'debug' the compiler may insert no-ops, other sequence point debugging info, etc.), but this does not imply that 'release' does any optimizations.

Comment: The debug build likely does some pessimizations that improve debugging, though

Comment: I guess it comes down to what counts as optimizations. Not inserting NOPs probably doesn't count as an optimization, but the compiler actually removes unused variables in release builds which I would consider an optimization.

Comment: The C# compiler certainly does optimizations. That is what the /o flag is for.  They are not very complex optimizations though.