# Why aren't Automatic Properties inlined by default?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, inline, jit

Being that properties are just methods under the hood, it's understandable that the performance of any logic they might perform may or may not improve performance - so it's understandable why the JIT needs to check if methods are worth inlining.

Automatic properties however (as far as I understand) cannot have any logic, and simply return or set the value of the underlying field. As far as I know, automatic properties are treated by the Compiler and the JIT just like any other methods.
**(Everything below will rely on the assumption that the above paragraph is correct.)**

Value Type properties show different behavior  than the variable itself, but Reference Type properties supposedly should have the exact same behavior as direct access to the underlying variable.

```
// Automatic Properties Example
public Object MyObj { get; private set; }
```

**Is there any case where automatic properties to `Reference Types` could show a performance hit by being inlined?

If not, what prevents either the Compiler or the JIT from automatically inlining them?**

Note: I understand that the performance gain would probably be insignificant, especially when the JIT is likely to inline them anyway if used enough times - but small as the gain may be, it seems logical that such a seemingly simple optimization would be introduced regardless.

Comment: Have you checked the generated IL ? How did you build (release/optimized versus debug) ? Are you on 32 or 64 bit ?

Comment: @Yahia I fail to understand how your comment has anything to do with my question... Automatic properties show up in the IL code as normal methods; just like normal properties do.

Comment: @Acidic "Automatic properties show up in the IL code ... just like normal properties do": you've answered your own question.  How would the jitter know that a property is an automatic property?  If you're asking why they're not inlined by the C# compiler, it's because *that would change the semantics of the code*.

Comment: @phoog I see no reason to why you view this matter as black or white, as if it either HAS to be a method, or not show up in the IL code at all. It could, for example, have some sort of unique signature attached that indicates to the JIT that the method is *by definition* worthy of inlining. Also, I see no reason to preserve the signature of properties that by definition have no logic behind them.

Comment: Offhand, my guess would be that no one at Microsoft has yet felt motivated enough to stop whatever else they were writing and see if this was worth the effort to do it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx

Comment: @Acidic To your first comment, yes, it might make sense for IL producers to be able to tag methods as worthy of inlining, but I would guess that the benefits (reduction in time needed to decide wether a method should be inlined) do not outweigh costs (increase in the size of the IL code). Plus, that's a change to the CLR, not just to C#.

Comment: @Acidic  As to the second comment, preserving signature of properties that have no logic behind them reduces breaking changes: it allows you to put logic behind them without requiring consumers to recompile their code. That's the reason behind the recommendation to use properties instead of fields in the first place. Allowing the compiler to undo that design by inlining the properties as public fields would undo the purpose of automatic properties.

Comment: @phoog Switching from a Reference-Type field to a Property will never change the implementation as far as I understand.

Comment: @Acidic not so; a field is a direct access of a member of a type, using the `ldfld` or `ldflda` IL instruction; property access is of course effected by a method call using the `call` or `callvirt` instruction.  That's true whether the member's type is a value type or a reference type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Automatic properties however (as far as I understand) cannot have any
>   logic, and simply return or set the value of the underlying field. As
>   far as I know, automatic properties are treated by the Compiler and
>   the JIT just like any other methods.

That automatic properties cannot have any logic is an implementation detail, there is not any special knowledge of that fact that is required for compilation. In fact, as you say auto properties are compiled down to method calls.

Suppose auto propes were inlined and the class and property are defined in a different assembly. This would mean that if the property implementation changes, you would have to recompile the application to see that change. That defeats using properties in the first place which should allow you to change the internal implementation without having to recompile the consuming application.

Comment: Well then it seems that they shouldn't be treated as normal methods.

Comment: @Acidic but the C# specification specifically defines properties as "like fields, but where a field defines a storage location, a property defines accessor methods" (paraphrasing section 1.6.7.2).  Since properties are defined as normal methods, why should the jitter not treat them as such?

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:  The JIT compiler doesn't work in the way you think it does, which I guess is why you're probably not completely understanding what I was trying to convey above. I've quoted your comment below:

> That is a different matter, but as far as I understand methods are only checked for being inline-worthy if they are called enough times. Not the mention that the checking itself is a performance hit. (Let the size of the performance hit be irrelevant for now.)

First, most, if not all, methods are checked to see if they can be inlined.  Second, keep in mind that methods are only ever JITed once and it is during that one time that the JITer will determine if any methods called *inside* of it will be inlined.  This can happen before any code is executed at all by your program.  What makes a called method a good candidate for inlining?

The x86 JIT compiler (x64 and ia64 don't necessarily use the same optimization techniques) checks a few things to determine if a method is a good candidate for inlining, definitely not just the number of times it is called.  [The article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/to-inline-or-not-to-inline-that-is-the-question) lists things like if inlining will make the code smaller, if the call site *will* be executed a lot of times (ie in a loop), and others.  Each method is optimized on its own, so the method may be inlined in one calling method but not in another, as in the example of a loop.  These optimization heuristics are only available to JIT, the C# compiler just doesn't know: it's producing IL, not native code.  There's a *huge* difference between them; native vs IL code size can be quite different.

To summarize, the C# compiler doesn't inline properties for performance reasons.

---

The jit compiler inlines most simple properties, including automatic properties.  You can read more about how the JIT decides to inline method calls [at this interesting blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/to-inline-or-not-to-inline-that-is-the-question).

Well, the C# compiler doesn't inline *any* methods at all.  I assume this is the case because of the way the CLR is designed.  Each assembly is designed to be portable from machine to machine.  A lot of times, you can change the internal behavior of a .NET assembly without having to recompile all the code, it can just be a drop in replacement (at least when types haven't changed).  If the code were inlined, it breaks that (great, imo) design and you lose that luster.

Let's talk about inlining in C++ first.  (Full disclosure, I haven't used C++ full time in a while, so I may be vague, my explanations rusty, or completely incorrect!  I'm counting on my fellow SOers to correct and scold me)

The C++ [inline keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88(v=vs.80).aspx) is like telling the compiler, "Hey man, I'd like you to inline this function, because I think it will improve performance".  <strike>Un</strike>fortunately, it is only telling the compiler you'd prefer it inlined; it is not telling it that it must.

Perhaps at an earlier date, when compilers were less optimized than they are now, the compiler would more often than not compile that function inlined.  However, as time went on and compilers grew smarter, the compiler writers discovered that in most cases, they were better at determining when a function should be inlined that the developer was.  For those few cases where it wasn't, developers could use the `seriouslybro_inlineme` keyword (officially called `__forceinline` in VC++).

Now, why would the compiler writers do this?  Well, inlining a function doesn't always mean increased performance.  While it certainly can, it can also *devastate* your programs performance, if used incorrectly.  For example, we all know one side effect of inlining code is increased code size, or "fat code syndrome" (disclaimer: not a real term).  Why is "fat code syndrome" a problem?  If you take a look at the article I linked above, it explains, among other things, memory is slow, and the bigger your code, the less likely it will fit in the fastest CPU cache (L1).  Eventually it can only fit in memory, and then, inlining has done nothing.  However, compilers know when these situations can happen, and do their best to prevent it.

Putting that together with your question, let's look at it this way: the C# compiler is like a developer writing code for the JIT compiler: the JIT is just smarter (but not a genius).  It often knows when inlining will benefit or harm execution speed.  "Senior developer" C# compiler doesn't have any idea how inlining a method call could benefit the runtime execution of your code, so it doesn't.  I guess that actually means the C# compiler is smart, because it leaves the job of optimization to those who are better than it, in this case, the JIT compiler.

Comment: Why should resources be wasted on running the method un-inlined at least a "few" times after which the JIT will start analyzing it to see if it is worth inling, as opposed to the compiler simply telling the JIT in advance that it should be inlined?

Comment: @Acidic, I 100% agree that it shouldn't happenand forunately, that's not how the JITer works.  The code is only JITed once, and so if it's not inlined or not.  It will never run a few times with the method call, and then later inlined.

Comment: That is a different matter, but as far as I understand methods are only checked for being inline-worthy if they are called enough times. Not the mention that the checking itself is a performance hit. (Let the size of the performance hit be irrelevant for now.)

Comment: That's perfectly true, but as the JITting happens _before_ execution, and not simultaneously, you lose your point... All that changes (marginally) is program startup time.

Comment: @Tobias- The JITer may not compile your entire program before it starts executing.  It does it on a type-by-type basis, but even then, it won't compile a static or instance level method until that method is called by another.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic properties are just that - property get/set methods generated automatically. As result there is nothing special in IL for them. C# compiler by itself does very [small number of optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937922/what-kind-of-optimizations-do-both-the-c-sharp-compiler-and-the-jit-do).

As for reasons why not to inline - imagine your type is in a separate assembly hence you are free to change source of that assembly to have insanely complicated get/set for the property. As result compiler can't reason on complexity of the get/set code when it sees your automatic property first time while creating new assembly depending on your type.

As you've already noted in your question - "especially when the JIT is likely to inline them anyway" - this property methods will likely be inlined at JIT time.

Comment: You've basically just repeated what I stated at the beginning. My question refers as to **why** it is so.

Comment: Yes - because you've answered your own question :) -"Why C# does not do something that JIT will do anyway and more reliable"?" - because it does not need too. Check out any answer by Eric Lippert on cost of features like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx.

Comment: You left out the fact that what the JIT does comes at the cost of worse performance.

Comment: Not sure I follow... If JIT inlines the method than it should be as if method was not there, if not - why C# compiler would inline it then?...

Comment: Because, to my knowledge, the method needs to run at a "certain frequency" before the JIT even considers checking if it is worth inlining, + the check itself obviously a performance hit. Also, I didn't specifically said that the Compiler has to inline it itself.

Comment: Looks like you are talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optimization which is not implemented by .Net jitter (at least standard one) to my knowledge, but found in Java VMs. .Net jitter does all work on first invocation of the method.